# Vincular variables entorno nodejs con nodemon

Tags: nodejs, backend

como se puede vincular las variables de entorno nodejs con nodemon? Actualmente nodejs ya no necesita de dotenv para la lectura de las variables.
Utilizando el siguiente código en la terminal, se ejecutan bien las variables:

```
node --env-file=.env app.js
```

Como es posible añadir a esto nodemon para el desarrollo?
PD: soy nuevo en Backend

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo agregando un script al package.json con el nombre 'dev', este suele ser el nombre elegido ya que queremos escuchar los cambios en los archivos con nodemon:

*.env:*

```
myenvvar=1234
```

*package.json:*

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon --env-file=.env index.js"
},
```

*index.js:*

```
console.log(process.env.myenvvar)
```

Y ejecutas la aplicación escribiendo 'npm run dev'. Con process.env obtienes las variables de entorno y no necesitas importar nada en el fichero. Aqui tienes mas informacion: [NodeJS env vars](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs)